# Why behave <T extends Record<number, X>> and <T extends Record<string, X>> differently for T[keyof T]?

Tags: typescript, generics, record

When I do this:

```
interface I<T extends Record<string, {b: boolean}>> {
  x: T[keyof T]['b'];
}
```

everything works, but as soon as I change `string` to `number`, I get `ts(2536): Type 'b' cannot be used to index type 'T[keyof T]'`. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the reason for this behaviour is that `Record<number, any>` also does accept array types.

Doing `I<{b: boolean}[]>` compiles correctly. But using `keyof` on an array type will also include a lot of other properties like `length` or method keys like `pop()` or `push()`. So when you do `T[keyof T]`, you will also get the types of these properties.

```
type ArrayValueof = {b: boolean}[][keyof []]
// type ArrayValueof = number | {
//     b: boolean;
// } | (() => IterableIterator<{
//     b: boolean;
// }>) | (() => {
//     copyWithin: boolean;
//     entries: boolean;
//     fill: boolean;
//     find: boolean;
//     findIndex: boolean;
//     keys: boolean;
//     values: boolean;
// }) | ... 28 more ... | ((searchElement: {
//     b: boolean;
// }, fromIndex?: number | undefined) => boolean)
```

As you can see, `{ b: boolean }` is part of this union but not every element in this union is an object with the property `b`. That's why you can not use `"b"` to index `T[keyof T]` when `T` also might be an array.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=45&pln=9&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIB4AqyIA9IgAmAzsgEoQID2Uh6IArgLYBG0ANMgN4sBcyLKlQA2EOCAC+APincAUMmS5+mANoBrCAE8qMZJgC6AbjkS5csFoAOKVAHdgYABYBBKFDhbkAXjToe-IIiYpKqBrJ4BCTIoDDQyADyyAD83KoA0jEgyJo6egkG-AkZBhLI-CAQAG7QcgD0dYrIAHrJ5hbWKG4eWgBqcMIMELo+3HwCQqLiEmEa2iNhBvWNiq3tljbI3Z7p83q+XBlZOXvIi-yZM7kLBksNTa1AA)

---

You can fix this issue by using an additional check:

```
interface I<T extends Record<number, {b: boolean}>> {
  x: T[T extends any[] ? number : keyof T]["b"];
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=3&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIB4AqyIA9IgAmAzsgEoQID2Uh6IArgLYBG0ANMgN4sBcyLKlQA2EOCAC%20APincAUMmS5%20mANrY8BEsnEBPVQF1kAfmSNW0ZPwDWEXVRjJMB1QCIWrgwG45EuXLBdAAcUAFFcIPE6TFkAXiccfAgiUlAYSwB5E25kVQBpZFBkW3tHDIN%20DPyjCSszCAA3aB8A4JRMAAZkePDIonQMCmpaemY2KE4uAX5BETEQZGkZOQB6FcVkAD1jf0CQpwBGbuReqIH0HhmhUXEJQ2W1je2gA)

Comment: Good point. Interestingly, `type X = Record<number, {b: boolean}>; type Y = X[keyof X]['b'];` works though, so the problem is probably introduced due to the generic.

Comment: Yes, in the `X` and `Y` example TypeScript knows that `X` is of type `Record<number, ...>`, so the `keyof X` will be `number`. In the generic type, `T` is only constrained to be `Record<number, ...>` but could also be tuple or array type since they also fulfill this constraint.

Comment: Here you can see a Playground without `Record` that also demonstrates the issue https://tsplay.dev/WJypVm